# Ionic 3 whit ion-menu lost rootpage when browser reload

Tags: routes, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I’m developing an app that targets both mobile an browser(PWA).
The home screen has a ion-menu to switch content and all pages use Ionic 3 IonicPage lazy loading.
In the browser I see the URL changing with pages for exemple:
If I choose “Contacts page” in menu (Home -> Menu -> Contacts)
“http://localhost:8100/#/home/contacts-main”.

Every thing works well, but if (for some reason) the browser reloads the page, the rootpage (with menu) is replaced with a content page (contacts page for exemple) and I cannot access the menu again.

How can I handle this to make the browser open in right page or loads on HomePage again?
I tried to configure defaultHistory explained in [IonicPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) but it is not the expected behavior.

Comment: do you have service worker enabled in your code? this could be potentially caching issue. Try to disable service worker in case it is enabled